# Update pandas dataframe column with another column in another dataframe on index overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to update column A in dfA with column B in dfB on index overlap

dfA

```
     A
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
```

dfB

```
     B
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
```

Desired result:

```
     A
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `update`

```
dfA.update(dfB.rename(columns = {'B':'A'}))
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you!

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing too! But slower 9 mins ;p